# How can I print out a single field in my multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

So I do a print for my object: print_r ($objMailer);

And I get the following below:

```
mymailer Object
(
[_strRecipient:mymailer:private] => 
[_strBcc:mymailer:private] => 
[_strSubject:mymailer:private] => 
[_strEmail:mymailer:private] => 
[_arrData:mymailer:private] => Array
(
    [full_name] => brian
    [invitee_name] => test
    [email] => test@testing.com
    [captcha] => kqd2q9
)

[_arrAttachments:mymailer:private] => 
[_blnCaptcha:mymailer:private] => 1
[_arrErrors:mymailer:private] => Array
(
)

)
```

I need to echo/print out just the 'full_name' field?  How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not trivially. As the `print_r` output shows that is within a private member.

You can either provide it from within your (?) `mymailer` object:

```
return $this->_arrData['full_name'];
```

or by using *Reflection* to make it accessible from the outside:

```
$refObj  = new ReflectionObject($objMailer);
$refProp = $refObj->getProperty('_arrData');
$array   = $refProp->getValue($objMailer);

echo $array['full_name'];
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. I ended up providing it within my mailer object. $this->_arrData['full_name']; into my mailer.php file  and then I was able to echo/print out the field in my controller file.  Thanks again, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Reflection provides quick and dirty access, but you shouldn't have to wrap an object by way of reflection simply to access a member variable. I'd suggest inspecting the object and using it's native accessors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to echo the value inside a method of `mymailer` class, you may use:

```
echo $this->_arrData['full_name'];
```

Comment: @Michael: so? All private properties are accessible within the class.

Comment: and you are accessing it outside the class with $objMailer, not inside via `$this`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's private you'll need to use a [getter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#PHP_example)

Answer (score 0):

The object you are referencing has an _arrData member variable which has private scope resolution, which means you cannot access it from outside the class. Chances are there is a public accessor which will allow you get the information you are after, but no way to tell unless you introspect the object itself.

I would suggest doing something like:

```
foreach (get_class_methods($mymailer) as $method) { echo 'M: ' . $method . '<br>'; } exit;
```

Then you can see the methods available to you, chances are there is a getData() method, with which you can do this:

```
$mailerData = $mymailer->getData();

var_dump($mailerData['full_name']);
```

There may even be a method to get the full name, something like this:

```
var_dump($mymailer->getFullname());
```